# "Do you still want me to do X" vs. "do you still want that I do X"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, particles

Which is correct?

> - Do you still want me **to** do the project for you?
> - Do you still want **that** I do the project for you?

Comment: The first is correct. The question is off topic for this forum, though

Comment: @mplungjan Why do you think the second may be incorrect? And, oh, why would the question be off topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ points out that there is one set of verbs that commonly occur with a *that*-clause (e.g. *think, say, know*) and a different set of verbs that commonly occur with a *to*-clause (e.g. ***want***, like, seem).

As a native speaker of British English, I would not say ‘Do you still want that . . .’ and that seems to be the general position. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has just 6 returns for the string ‘want that I’, against 4770 for ‘want me to’. The figures for the smaller British National Corpus are 4 and 927.

Comment: Why do I see a semantic difference here? 'You want me to do' doesn't quite seem to mean the same as 'You want that I do'. I might use the two structures in different contexts.

Comment: I can only repeat that, as a native speaker of British English, I would not use the _that_ construction with _want_. It sounds like something a non-native speaker would say.